# What's the Performance Penalty of Throwing an Error in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I was reading the great book *Writing High-Performance .NET Code* by *Ben Watson* and he was saying to try avoid throwing exceptions in `.NET` code because of the horrible performance they create (having to grab a stack trace etc). So, I was wondering. Does SQL Server create a trace of the error or is it more simple? Are there any performance implications for throwing an error in SQL Server? Does this exception end up causing performance problems when it reaches the C# code?

I thought I would ask before I write test code for it, if anyone knew already. Since writing tests can be tricky and I don't have much time to do it outside of work.

Comment: See https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2632/checking-for-potential-constraint-violations-before-entering-sql-server-try-and-catch-logic/ and https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/error-handling ... it can cause a performance impact in SQL Server, that's what I focused on, if it also causes overhead in C#, that's for the app people to sort out.